# Add social icons to footer in mobile

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to add social icons in the footer of my mobile application (Facebook, Youtube, Twitter, Whatsapp). I'm using *xamarin* cross platform to build my application.

Comment: You could add them to a toolbar, however for android / ios this in the top ofpage

Answer (score 0):

A mobile app doesn't really have a footer of sorts, and putting social icons in it seems more like a thing you would do on a website to me. However, it is fairly easy to create an element that is always at the bottom of the page. You could use a `StackLayout` with `VerticalOptions` set to `EndAndExpand` which will vertically put it at the bottom or you could create a `Grid` structure to ensure the content is always at the bottom.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        // Normal content
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Twitter" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Facebook" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```